# getting java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD4 MessageDigest not available for java 17

Tags: java, java-17, smbj

I'm facing the exception `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD4 MessageDigest not available`.

I'm using the library in java 17 and gradle - `implementation group: 'com.hierynomus', name: 'smbj', version: '0.9.1'`

Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in smbj; see https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj/issues/425.  According to the issue updates, a fix has been committed and is included in smbj release 0.12.2.

Solution: upgrade your dependency.

(FWIW, 0.9.1 is nearly 5 years out of date ... at the time of writing this.)

---

For those (like me) whose initial reaction was "but MD4 is insecure", there are a few protocols where MD4 is still used.  SMB appears to be one of them.

Comment: Thanks, changed dependency to 0.12.0 instead of 0.12.2. along with this i also updated few more deps. its working.